# При попытке переустановить Ubuntu попадаю в grub-меню

Tags: ubuntu, grub

Всем привет.

Слетела Убунта.
Хочу переустановить.
Создал загрузочную флешку с помощью утилиты "Создать загрузочный диск" (из другой Убунты) и образа "ubuntu-20.10-desktop-amd64.iso", который скачал с официального сайта.
Ноутбук DELL Inspirion 15 3000 Series.
При запуске нажимаю F12, выбираю в качестве источника загрузки мою загрузочную флешку.
Попадаю в grub-меню.
Как запустить установку ОС?

С уважением, Александр.

[image: GRUB]

Comment: Одно из двух: либо ваша флешка неправильно записалась, либо не получилось настроить загрузку с флешки. Grub явно от прошлой установленной системы.

Comment: Если есть время, попробуйте [Arch](https://archlinux.org/). Вам понравится.

Answer (score 0):

По идее, если выбрать первый пункт меню, ОС должна загрузиться с флешки и на рабочем столе должна быть программа установки. Но рабочий стол загружался пустым. Ничего нельзя было сделать, просто шевелить мышкой. Подозреваю, что скачал кривой образ.

Скачал образ "linuxmint-20-cinnamon-64bit.iso". Первый пункт grub-меню отработал. Загрузился функциональный рабочий стол и я запустил установку ОС. Давно хотел попробовать Mint, вот представилась такая возможность :)